# Simplest minecraft pe server

Tags: java, udp

I tried to make a simple server which only displays its info on servers list in Minecraft Windows 10 Edition version 1.1.5. (answers to the client's ping)
like the Breadix:
[image: servers list]

Here is my code:

```java
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import me.theentropyshard.grasspath.raknet.Binary;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.Random;

public class Server {
    private static Server instance = null;

    public static final byte[] RAKNET_MAGIC = new byte[]{
            0x00, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, 0x00,
            (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0xfe,
            (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0xfd,
            0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};

    protected Server() {
        instance = this;
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 19132));
            ByteBuf byteBuffer = Unpooled.buffer();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
            while(true) {
                if(packet.getData()[0] == 0x01) {
                    long pingID = Binary.readLong(packet.getData());
                    System.out.println("long " + pingID);
                    byteBuffer.clear();
                    DatagramPacket p2 = new DatagramPacket(byteBuffer.array(), 0, byteBuffer.array().length);
                    p2.setAddress(packet.getAddress());
                    String text = "MCPE;My Server;113;1.1.5;0;20";
                    byteBuffer.writeByte(0x1c);
                    byteBuffer.writeLong(pingID);
                    byteBuffer.writeLong(new Random().nextLong());
                    byteBuffer.writeBytes(RAKNET_MAGIC);
                    byteBuffer.writeShort(text.length());
                    byteBuffer.writeBytes(text.getBytes());
                    p2.setData(byteBuffer.array());
                    socket.send(p2);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Server getServer() {
        return Server.instance;
    }
```

I have read some articles about raknet, udp:

[Documentation](https://wiki.vg/Pocket_Edition_Protocol_Documentation)
[Protocol](https://wiki.vg/Pocket_Minecraft_Protocol)

Also I looked at this lib, it shows info, but it outdated and has problem, but it is another story:
[JRakLibPlus](https://github.com/alejzeis/JRakLibPlus)

I get the ping packet from the client (0x01) but cant figure out how to send pong packet (0x1c).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the example below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Random;

final class Main {
    private static DatagramSocket server;
    private static InetAddress address;
    private static final int PORT = 19132;
    private static DatagramPacket packetReceive;
    private static final byte[] BYTE_RECEIVE = new byte[8192];
    private static DatagramPacket packetSend;
    private static final byte[] BYTE_SEND = new byte[8192];
    private static final byte[] OFFLINE_MESSAGE_DATA_ID = {
            0, (byte) 0xff,
            (byte) 0xff,
            0, (byte) 0xfe,
            (byte) 0xfe,
            (byte) 0xfe,
            (byte) 0xfe,
            (byte) 0xfd,
            (byte) 0xfd,
            (byte) 0xfd,
            (byte) 0xfd,
            (byte) 0x12,
            (byte) 0x34,
            (byte) 0x56,
            (byte) 0x78
    };
    private static final String serverId = "MCPE;Dedicated Server;589;1.20.1;0;10;13253860892328930865;Bedrock level;Survival;1;19132;19133";

    public static void main(String[] a) throws IOException {
        address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        server = new DatagramSocket(PORT, address);

        packetReceive = new DatagramPacket(BYTE_RECEIVE, BYTE_RECEIVE.length);

        for (; ; ) {
            server.receive(packetReceive);
            if (packetReceive.getData()[0] == 1) {
                final int lengthServerId = serverId.getBytes().length;
                final ByteBuffer bufReceive = ByteBuffer.wrap(packetReceive.getData());
                final ByteBuffer bufSend = ByteBuffer.allocate(Byte.BYTES + (Long.BYTES * 2) + OFFLINE_MESSAGE_DATA_ID.length + (Short.BYTES + lengthServerId));
                bufSend.put((byte) 0x1c);
                bufSend.putLong(bufReceive.getLong(1));
                bufSend.putLong(new Random().nextLong());
                bufSend.put(OFFLINE_MESSAGE_DATA_ID);
                bufSend.put(
                        ByteBuffer.allocate(Short.BYTES + lengthServerId)
                                .putShort((short) serverId.length())
                                .put(serverId.getBytes())
                                .array()
                );

                packetSend = new DatagramPacket(BYTE_SEND, BYTE_SEND.length, packetReceive.getAddress(), packetReceive.getPort());
                packetSend.setData(bufSend.array());
                server.send(packetSend);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I see you are missing `p2.setPort(packet.getPort());`.

I hope the above answer is helpful to you.